# Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater is not updating according to frequency

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

The code below does not update according to frequency; 
It is just updating once at the beginning

```
  new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('message_field', "http://localhost:8888/lsl_application/php/update_message_field.php?"+param, {
            method: "GET",
            frequency: 2,
            decay: 1,
            onSuccess: onSuccess_forPeriodic,
            onFailure: function(xhrResponse){
                alert("Failed to update!"+xhrResponse.statusText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you please add a liitle more explanation to your question, or, a question at all? You're merely telling us what your code is, not what your exact problem and situation is.

Comment: The code is executing just once and it is not updating according to frequency value every 2 seconds

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Prototype's PeriodicalUpdater, so I added the prototypejs tag. If I'm mistaken, please edit your question to include what component/library/framework you are using. Note that it is unlikely anyone will be able to help you with the small amount of information you've given here. Please read [ask] to find what might help.

Comment: Just making sure here: does the result / the source that's being queried actually change? Did you by any chance call the [#stop](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/PeriodicalUpdater/prototype/stop/) instance method after the first run, maybe in `onSuccess_forPeriodic`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi according to your question I have made sample application as below. It looks like your web service/API is taking some time to process your request.

Please try to run as below example you may have an answer to your question.

> My Client Code, Index.php, request every second.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('message_field', "time.php", {
            method: "GET",
            frequency: 1,
            //asynchronous: false,
            onSuccess: function(s){
                document.getElementById("t").innerText = s.responseText;
            },
            onFailure: function(xhrResponse){
                alert("Failed to update!"+xhrResponse.statusText);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="t"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

> Server Code, time.php, Web Service/API logic.

```
<?php 

sleep(5);

echo date('h:i:s A'); 

?>
```

> **Note:** Please have look to the Network of your browser. I have the frequency of 1 while answer comes at every 5 seconds.

[image]

Comment: This is producing the same result as yours

Comment: This is what I am trying to explain, that web service/API function taking little time to execute so frequency is not running in the timely fashion.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/PeriodicalUpdater/ the frequency is the amount of time that the code waits between the end of the first request to when the next request is started.

For example what you are expecting is this

```
function poll()
{

    //function body

}

setInterval(poll,2000);
```

However what `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater` does is this

```
function poll()
{

    //function body

    setTimeout(poll,2000);
}

poll();
```

The benefit of waiting till the first(previous) request is finished prevents the UI from hammering the backend code every 2 seconds regardless of how fast the backend process runs. Especially if the backend process takes 2 seconds or longer to process, it will cause the requests to stack.

Also I believe you might be using it incorrectly as `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater` is simply a wrapper around `Ajax.Updater` which does the content update for you. I could be wrong as I can't see the rest of your code. The code snippet you provided should be updating the element with id `message_field` with the response from your URL request. That content update is fired on the onComplete event which is *after* the onSuccess event. So if the URL response is not changing as it does in Jenish Zinzuvadiya's answer then you would see that behavior.

I hope I was able to help.